# Why do my tooltips flash in Firefox and not Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, fullcalendar, wijmo

If you view the following fiddle in Firefox (FF 5.0.1 Mac in my case) and hover over a day in the calendar so that the mouse pointer is inside the tooltip, the tooltip flashes on and off. This doesn't happen in chrome. Anyone know that is going on here?

http://jsfiddle.net/codecowboy/BP4Hp/

I haven't upgraded to FF 6 yet because of incompatibility issues with Firephp. I just want to understand what might be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the closeBehavior of the tooltip to "sticky" resolved the issue for me. It helps to spell it as it is written in the docs! (the american way). I had used the british spelling in my app and so couldn't figure out why my tooltips were flashing on and off.

Answer (score 1):

Because $('.wijmo-wijtooltip') adding to body, so when you mouse enter in this tooltip, your calendar field lost focus, but after loosing focus, your mouse pointer again trigger mouseenter event

In my Chromium I get same behavior as in FF.

Comment: I'm not seeing that class being added to the <body> tag

Comment: [http://fiddle.jshell.net/codecowboy/BP4Hp/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/codecowboy/BP4Hp/show/) - here you have only two children of body tag:
#fc which contain your calendar widget
and .wijmo-wijtooltip container which contain your tooltip